# form submission using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to bootstrap API but I am not finding any documentation on what I am looking to do. I have access to about 5 textbooks on bootstrap via SafariBooks, all of which have turned up nothing. My dilemma: I'm working on a simple login form. Here is what I have:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
          <fieldset>
            <div id="legend">
              <legend class="">Login</legend>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <!-- Username -->
              <label class="control-label"  for="username">Username</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <!-- Password-->
              <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <!-- Button -->
              <div class="controls">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would love to know is, how do I retrieve the values from the two fields using javascript when clicking login? My goal is to pass the values to my Parse database. To my knowledge I need to pass the form to a script, where I could then call "form.Email" or something along those lines, just not sure how to get there.

I just can't seem to find any clear examples. I've been digging for about two hours into this with no luck and I'm aware it's a rookie question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways to get input to jquery. After that you can form ajax post request to a specific link with data you want to transfer.

```
$('.btn-success').click(function() {
    var username = $('#username').val()
    //do whatever you want with the value
    $.ajax({
      //object parameters goes here
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick='myFunction'>Login</button>
<script>
    function myFunction( e ){
        var myUsername = document.getElemetById( "username" ).value;
        var myPassword = document.getElemetById( "password" ).value;
    }
</script>
```

`myUsername` and `myPassword` will contain values of your fields